# Realtek RTL8187B stopped working

Tags: wireless, realtek, atheros, backport, modprobe

I have Ubuntu 13.10 Server running 3.11 kernel

I had RTL8187B working out of the box but after installing Atheros driver (for another adapter) my RealTek stopped working, I used BackPorts to install the Atheros driver

I looked at `/lib/modules/` and the module wasn't recently modified but when I try `modprobe rtl8187` I get `ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8187': Invalid argument`

This is the output of  `dmesg | tail`

> [ 3097.162711] rtl8187: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling
>
> [ 3097.162716] rtl8187: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling (err -22)
>
> [ 3097.162739] rtl8187: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw
>
> [ 3097.162744] rtl8187: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
>
> [ 3097.162757] rtl8187: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
>
> [ 3097.162761] rtl8187: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)
>
> [ 3097.162800] rtl8187: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rx_irqsafe
>
> [ 3097.162805] rtl8187: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rx_irqsafe (err -22)
>
> [ 3097.162828] rtl8187: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rts_duration
>
> [ 3097.162833] rtl8187: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rts_duration (err -22)

Any suggestions?

Comment: One of the kernel or the driver got updated, but the other did not. Do a full upgrade (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`). If that does not fix your problem, then you should consider upgrading to 14.04.

Comment: I can't upgrade my system, I need a software that only runs on Ubuntu 13.10. In addition, I didn't update the kernel and the driver was last updated in 2013.

Comment: Can you post the output of `uname -a`

Comment: `Linux Robin-01 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:12:00 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux` @bain

Comment: It might help to upgrade your kernel, it is out of date - the latest for Ubuntu 13.10 is [3.11.0.26.27]. How did you install the Atheros driver? There is no atheros driver in saucy-backports.

Comment: I believe there is a conflict in the way the 80211 stack is handled between the two methods you used. I suggest you install both drivers using the same method, presumably backports. Did you compile backports or install linux-backports-modules-cw?

Comment: @bain I compiled the sources files from here http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/

Comment: Either do as chili555 suggests and install both drivers from backports, or install a later kernel that supports both (e.g. you could install the latest 14.04 kernel if that supports your Atheros hardware)

Comment: Support for 13.10 ended on July 17, 2014.  I recommend you upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: @chili555 Please answer the question here to mark your answer as the right one, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both ath9k and rtl8187 in backports-3.15 with:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15.1-1  <--or wherever you extracted it
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Backports currently won't compile on the latest Ubuntu kernels so I suggest that, for now, you stick with 13.10. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1342703

You will have compiled the drivers for your currently running kernel only. When a later linux-image is installed, after the requested reboot, re-compile as above.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was discussed here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234803